# Defining arrays in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm a javascript newbie and trying to write a script for a spreadsheet that will pull various things out of it. Right off the bat, I'm having trouble defining an array of names that will be in the spreasheet. The error says "Missing ; before statement (line 10)"

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  //var values = rows.getValues();

  var Names = sheet.getRange("A2:A7");
  var Name = new Array(6);
  var Name_cell = Names.getCell(1, 1);
  var Name[0] = Name_cell.getValue();  //  <-- Here's the issue
  var Name_cell = Names.getCell(2, 1);
  var Name[1] = Name_cell.getValue();
  var Name_cell = Names.getCell(3, 1);
  var Name[2] = Name_cell.getValue();
  var Name_cell = Names.getCell(4, 1);
  var Name[3] = Name_cell.getValue();
  var Name_cell = Names.getCell(5, 1);
  var Name[4] = Name_cell.getValue();
  var Name_cell = Names.getCell(6, 1);
  var Name[5] = Name_cell.getValue();

  // ...
}
```

Comment: its javascript, not java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  //var values = rows.getValues();

  var Names = sheet.getRange("A2:A7");
  var Name = [
    Names.getCell(1, 1).getValue(),
    Names.getCell(2, 1).getValue(),
    .....
    Names.getCell(5, 1).getValue()]
```

You can define arrays simply as follows, instead of allocating and then assigning.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,5]
```

Your initial error was because of the following line, and ones like it

```
var Name[0] = Name_cell.getValue();
```

Since `Name` is already defined and you are assigning the values to its elements, you should skip the `var`, so just

```
Name[0] = Name_cell.getValue();
```

Pro tip: For most issues that, like this one, don't directly involve Google services, you are better off Googling for the way to do it in javascript in general.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Googling, but apparently I wasn't using the right keywords

Answer (score 4):

I think that maybe it is because you are declaring a variable that you already declared:

```
var Name = new Array(6);
//...
var Name[0] = Name_cell.getValue();  //  <-- Here's the issue: 'var'
```

I think this should be like this:

```
var Name = new Array(6);
//...
Name[0] = Name_cell.getValue();
```

Tell me if it works! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help to a few who are struggling like I was:

```
var data = myform.getRange("A:AA").getValues().pop();
var myvariable1 = data[4];
var myvariable2 = data[7];
```

Comment: getRange("A:AA") - should be getRange("A1:AA1") or whatever row ;-0